# Does the quotient of the dyadic and ternary rationals greater than $1$ by their powers of $3$ have the trivial topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, quotient-spaces

Consider two topological spaces:

1. Begin with $X_{>0}$ the positive dyadic and ternary rationals (including products e.g. $\frac n6$), with their topology as a subspace of $\Bbb R$.  Then consider the quotient space $X_{>0}/\langle3\rangle$ given by completing the equivalence relation $x\sim 3x$ or in other words:

   $x\sim y\iff\exists i\in\Bbb Z:3^ix=y$
2. As above, but now begin with $X_{>1}$ the dyadic and ternary rationals (including products) greater than $1$ and take the quotient $X_{>1}/\langle3\rangle$ using the same equivalence relation.

**Question**

Do these quotient spaces have a nontrivial topology?

**Attempt**

$\Bbb R$ is a metric space.  Therefore the quotient topology is the same as the toplogy given by the [quotient pseudometric](https://mathoverflow.net/a/123753/91341), right?  Or are there other Hausdorff quotient topologies?

Then for case 1: its topology IS trivial because I can pick arbitrarily large $i$ such that $d(3^{-i}x,3^{-i}y)$ is arbitrarily small in the vicinity of $0$.

For case 2: There's a prima facie argument that this quotient is Hausdorff because for any pair $x,y$ there's some maximal $i_1,i_2$ such that $\lvert 3^{i_1}x-3^{i_2}y\rvert$ is a difference between two representatives greater than $1$ - guaranteeing disjoint vicinities around them.  But this isn't conclusive because correctly using the quotient metric involves finding the shortest distance between two elements in $X_{>1}/\langle3\rangle$ using any sequence of stepping stones in-between.  I'm pretty much baffled how to do that.  How do I determine a non-recursive function for the pseudometric?

**Update**

For the reasons given in this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/380398/91341 which is largely the same as this problem, I am satisfied that the quotient pseudometric is the trivial $\forall x,y:d(x,y)=0$.  I am of the view however that the quotient topology itself is NOT trivial, although I cannot show it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $[x],[y]\in X_{>1}/\langle3\rangle$ with $x,y\in X_{>1}$ the least
element of their respective equivalence classes. I claim that
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:pseudometric}
d([x],[y])=|3^{-i}x-3^{-j}y|  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $i$ and $j$ are the unique nonnegative intergers for which
$1\leq 3^{-i}x,3^{-j}y<3$. Note that $3^{-i}x$ and $3^{-j}y$ are only
contained in $[x]$ and $[y]$ if they are ternary. However, since the
ternary rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ it suffices to prove (1)
for both $x$ and $y$ ternary. Accordingly, suppose both $x$ and $y$
are both ternary and the least element of their equivalence
class. Thus, $1\leq x, y<3$ so that (1) asserts that
$d([x],[y])=|x-y|$. If $a\sim x$ and $b\sim y$ with $a\neq x$ then
$|a-b|>|x-y|$ so that $|x-y|<|x-a|+|a-b|+|b-y|$. Thus, the infimum of all
the lengths of chains from $x$ to $y$ is $|x-y|$ so that (1) holds.

Comment: Apologies, I realise I have been ambiguous at best and misleading at worst in my question. Did you include e.g. $\frac76$ in $X$ which is a product of both dyadic and ternary rationals?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realise you meant to include products.

Comment: Please don't delete. As the case of ternary rationals can still serve as a useful example for me to think about, which I plan to do today... if not correctable I may also be able to edit the question to suit your answer.

Comment: For each $x\in X_{>1}$ there exists a unique nonnegative integer $i$
for which $1\leq 3^{-i}x<3$. Note that $x^*=3^{-i}x\in [x]$ and is the
least element.  Let $[x],[y]\in X_{>1}/\langle3\rangle$. I claim that
$$  d([x],[y])=|x^*-y^*|.  \tag{1}$$

Let $\{a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ and $\{b_0,b_1,\dots,b_n\}$ be any chain
between $x$ and $y$. Then,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |b_i-a_{i+1}|
\geq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |b_i^*-a_{i+1}^*|
=|x^*-a_1^*|+|b_1^*-a_1^*|+\cdots +|b_{n-1}^*-y^*|\geq |x^*-y^*|. $$
Hence, (1) holds.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I was unable to give some time to this for the past few days.  Are we in agreement that $d([26],[10])=\left\lvert\dfrac{26}9-\dfrac{30}9\right\rvert=\dfrac49<\left\lvert\dfrac{26}9-\dfrac{10}9\right\rvert$ is a counterexample to your claimed proof?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me think about the problem but in the absence of a rebuttal of my counterexample, I'll flag as not an answer since the claim is untrue.

Comment: Of course that is correct.

Comment: So for $x^*<y^*$ is it $d([x],[y])=\min\{|x^*-y^*|,( x^*-1)+(3-y^*)\}$?

Comment: for $x^*>y^*$ there is a case for $\min\{x^*-y^*,3y^*-x^*\}$ but we would first have to prove there can be no chains of intermediate representatives that bring them closer together. I'll have to think harder about what you suggest in the morning and work out why it could be that. The 2nd half of your proposal is $x^*-y^*+2$. How did you arrive at this?

Comment: I meant the minimum of the distance between $x^*$ and $y^*$ and the sum of their distances from the boundary of $[1,3]$.

Comment: I am satisfied that any attempt to resolve this by use of a metric space is doomed to fail, because of the reasons in this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/380398/91341 the pseudometric will be the trivial $\forall x,y:d(x,y)=0$